# Convert a class to Fragment Object

Tags: android, class, object, android-fragments

How can I cast a class to fragment? I have the following scenario:

Fragment fragment;

Now i want to assign some value to this fragment like:

fragment= SomeClass.class.

How cani type cast it.? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to cast SomeClass as a Fragment? If SomeClass is a subclass of Fragment then you shouldn't have to cast it to store a reference in a Fragment variable, only to retrieve it as a SomeClass. If SomeClass is not a subclass of Fragment you shouldn't be trying to cast it as one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax:fragment= SomeClass.class if SomeClass extends Fragment. Another way: SomeClass can implements Fragment, then in the code:

```
fragment= (Fragment)SomeClass.class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
It works for me.

```
    Class  cur_class_frag = null;
        switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    cur_class_frag =  Some_Fragment_Class.class;
                    cur_frag="recipees";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cur_class_frag =  Facebook_Fragment_Class.class; //facebok

                    cur_frag="facebook";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cur_class_frag =  Twitter_Fragment_Class.class;  //twitter
                    cur_frag="twitter";
                   default:
                    break;
                }
android.app.FragmentManager fragmanager = getFragmentManager(); 
        //check if  tag already exists
        Fragment fragment2 = fragmanager.findFragmentByTag(cur_frag);

        if (fragment2 !=null) {
            //remove and add in content frame
            fragmanager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment2).commit();

            fragmanager.beginTransaction()
            //.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2,cur_frag)
            .commit();

            }
        else{
            //create it :)

            Fragment frag = null;
            try {
                frag = (Fragment) cur_class_frag.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            fragmanager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, frag,cur_frag).commit();
```

here i am switching a menu position from which i take the current fragment and if doesn't already exist i create it else i re-add it.
also i Cast the Fragment Class Name as fragment. -- if the Class does not exist i haven't checked it.-- so be carefull